# Set a var in XCode for use in build

Tags: xcode

I don't want to set a global env-var, but it would be handy to set a single var in an XCode project which is then usable in the various build-steps. e.g I want to set `MY_PATH = /usr/local/MyLib` and then use `$(MY_PATH)` in search paths and `${MY_PATH}` in script build-steps.

I'm using XCode 3.2.6. Is there a way to set project-local env-vars or similar?

Even better would be if it's not stored in the main project file so it can not be checked into source control - maybe I'm expecting it to be too similar to Visual Studio!

Answer (score 1):

Add a user-defined build setting. Open the build settings inspector in Xcode 3.2.6 (Xcode 4 changed things considerably) by choosing Project > Edit Project Settings. In the lower left corner of the inspector is a button with a pull down menu. Click the button and choose Add User-Defined Setting.